# Disable Category Page Description Content from showing on Filtered Results

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, layered-navigation

In our category pages the `description` attribute shows at the top of the page. This section is really helpful for the initial category experience.

## Problem:

When the user filters down the category, the `description` still displays. At that point.. the `description` isn't so helpful, is redundant and takes up valuable above the food space.

## Question:

How can we limit the `description` from only showing on the non-filtered version of the category page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can get the filters that are currently applied.

```
$filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
```

Now all you need to do is to edit `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/catalog/category/view.phtml` and add an if statement around the category description (maybe the image also) to check if there are filters applied:

So change this:

```
<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php $filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters(); ?>
<?php if (!$filters) : ?>

    <?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
        <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>
     <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Perfect! I was working with something really close (` $_filters = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();`) but it wasn't quite working. you nailed it! Thanks Marius